# WebApi .Net Core error as does not contain definition for GetAwaiter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm new to .NET Core, and I'm reading this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

From there I'm practicing - I write this logic:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<DashBoar>>> GetAllAsync()
{
    var x = _Repo.GetPetsAsync();
    return await x.ToList();
}
```

But I'm getting an error.

My repo class is

```
public IEnumerable<DashBoar> GetPetsAsync()
{
    var x = from n in _context.DashBoar
            select n;
    return  x.ToList();
}
```

Comment: `_Repo.GetPetsAsync()` is the asynchronous operation, not `x.ToList()`

Comment: I think you must use `ToListAsync()`.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Could u plz Help me in This Conetxt

Comment: @Llazar In Above Logic Insted of x.tolist if I Write  return  await x.ToListAsync(); Im Getting Error

Comment: I could tell you what to do, but you won't learn anything out of it. Just keep reading the tutorial because your code is far from what the tutorial shows

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Could u please Reffere Me any Links

Comment: You **Must NOT** Capitalize Each And Every Single Word in the English language ....

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. One golden rule here on Stack Overflow (and in general when asking questions), if you say you're getting an error, we **absolutely** require you to post as much details about that error as you can. This includes stack trace, exception type and message (if it's a runtime exception), or the exact output of the error, as well as a pinpoint to which line of code that is causing the error (at least as far as you can identify).

Comment: The reason why the compiler is complaining here is that you're awaiting the result of calling `ToList`, basically it looks like this: `await (x.ToList());`. Instead you could write it like this: `(await x).ToList();`. However, the answer provided by Asela is far more expressive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should first understand what asynchronous programming is and the co-relation of await, async and Task.

Asynchronous programming is used to improve the application performance and enhance the responsiveness. Refer the links at the bottom to get an understanding.

First let's address your problem.
Make your repo class return type as a Tak

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<DashBoar>> GetPetsAsync()
{
     var x = await (from n in _context.DashBoar
             select n).ToListAsync();

     return x;
}
```

Then call the repo method from GetAllAsync() method as below

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<DashBoar>>> GetAllAsync()
{
     var x = await _Repo.GetPetsAsync();
     return x;
}
```

Please go through the below links To get a better understanding of asynchronous programming.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5VhaxQWcpE

https://www.dotnetperls.com/async

Good luck..!